# store user info in wp database and separate database on registration

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a site for company that is already using a program for scheduling clients, and keeping their information. This program also allows web access to the database. On the site I've chosen to use Wordpress due to some of their requirements.

My problem is they want to allow people to register online. So **if I create a custom registration form, how can I store some data in the wordpress database, and the rest in another database?**

I'm also planning on calling the programs database to display additional information about the user on the site, such as their schedule. Am I going in the wrong direction, will this cause problems in the future?

Additional info:

- The program they use is called Links Modular Solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to specify two connections for different databases and store what you what and where you want.

e.g. algorithm as follows:

```
# connect to db1 host
# select db1
# query/insert db1
# connect to db2 host
# select db2
# query/insert db2
```

Needless to say that you will need both db access data and access to the PHP scripts/server

Comment: makes sense, but I'm not sure how wordpress handles their database connections. My main concern is security that's part of why I chose wordpress. so while I guess I could make my own database connection and insert a new WP user. I'm not sure about security, I'm very new in that area. I know it's a broad subject, but are there any good articles or examples on securing this that you would recommend?

Comment: Found out about the wpdb class WordPress uses. Not only can I use it to safely connect to the WordPress database, but I can use it to more securely connect and add to another database. So your answer combined with this new knowledge is perfect. Thanks for your help